# Can anyone identify the country, rank, and unit of this WWI Uniform?

Tags: world-war-one, identification, uniform

A photograph of my grandfather, Stephen Peter Barbustiak (sp of last name changed during immigration process). DOB 20 August 1895 in Odorin, present day Slovakia. Married September 3, 1917. I know he served in Eastern Europe during World War One.[image: Seated man wearing high collared uniform with epaulettes]

Comment: Please include everything you know about your grandfather: D.O.B., full name, ranks achieved, any medals, where born, when immigrated, where lived, etc. These clues are of great help in tracking these pictures down. Also include guesses/estimates - but mark them as such distinct from known facts.

Comment: Stephen Peter Barbustiak  (sp of last name changed during immigration process) . DOB 20 August 1895 in Odorin, present day Slovakia. Married September 3, 1917.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, subject to arbitrary deletion at any time. Please edit all additional details in tot the question body itself.

Comment: Thanks, looks like someone edited the question to add the information. I am a first time user.

Comment: If it's an Austro-Hungarian uniform, the six-pointed star near the tip of the color suggests a Gefreiter.  The lollipop-like emblem a few cm away from that  would be some kind of branch or speciality emblem (in this case, balloon corps?).

Comment: Thanks you @kimchi-lover . Your observation makes sense. Family lore is that my Grandfather served in the Austro-Hungarian Army and repaired balloons since he was a tailor by trade. We believe he served outside of Vienna during the war.

Answer (score 4):

I believe [@kimchi lover is correct](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/62681/can-anyone-identify-the-country-rank-and-unit-of-this-wwi-uniform#comment195989_62681). The single six-pointed star is that of a [Gefreiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gefreiter#Austria), an enlisted man who has been promoted once, roughly equivalent to a [NATO OR-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranks_and_insignia_of_NATO_armies_enlisted) or US Private 1st Class.

The "lollipop-like emblem" on the collar is a [balloon](https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Visit/Museum-Exhibits/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/601462/austro-hungarian-balloon-corp-collar-insignia/), but does not necessarily mean he was in the balloon corps. It indicates he was in the [Air Service](http://todd.mainecav.org/swwisa/kuklft/) which began as a balloon corps. In 1917 the Air Service operated both airplanes and balloons.

A [Field Pilot's Badge](http://www.austro-hungarian-army.co.uk/badges/feldpil.html) over his right breast would be definitive proof that he was a pilot, its lack does not rule it out.

Unfortunately I cannot make out the medals over his left breast pocket.

Comment: Given the floral decorations on the bride, the apparent 'plasticity' of the decorations over his left breast may be partially plant matter as well? (what is that? Ferns? – Anyway: Making any 'medals' even harder to gauge)/ His shirt cuffs seem to be of special quality? His single button tunic cuff and foot wear seem also a bit noteworthy to me.